# Python type factory instead of object factory

Tags: python

I was researching options to implement a factory for types with different numbers of constructor arguments.
The majority of examples suggest factories that return fully constructed objects. That leaves it to the factory to handle the different number of arguments.

Since in Python types can be return values, I was wondering, if I can have something like a *type factory*.

The idea is to have the factory return a type instead of an object. And call this type's CTOR with whichever argument list is appropriate.

A minimal, runnable example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class TypeA:
    def __init__(self, arg: int):
        self._data = arg

class TypeB:
    def __init__(self, arg: int, flag: bool = False):
        self._data = arg
        self._flag = flag

def getType(option: str):
    if option == 'A':
        return TypeA
    elif option == 'B':
        return TypeB
    else:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Type '{option}' cannot be resolved")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    objA = getType(option='A')(42)
    objB1 = getType(option='B')(arg=4711, flag=True)
    objB2 = getType(option='B')(arg=815)
    objInvalid = getType(option='C')()
```

So far I have not seen this mentioned anywhere.
(Even though it is not immediately related to addressing the problem of variable length argument lists I could imagine, that  dynamic type information could be useful in other  contexts where the intent is not the creation of an object).

I am wondering if there is anything that speaks against using this variant of a factory for creating different types. Thoughts?

Comment: Should `createType()` be renamed to `getType()`?

Comment: Agree, I will edit my question.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "factory" since it never actually creates anything, but it's certainly a perfectly cromulent design pattern.